# Need to read different line from different files using CSV read function in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a 2 files like below. In each csv, i have two columns for example : username and password details.

Ex : c://user.txt1.csv, c://user.txt2.csv files.

My scenario is like below

first iteration - i need to read from txt1.csv and 1st line.
Second iteration - i need to read from txt2.csv and 1st line.
Third iteration - i need to read from txt1.csv and 2nd line.
Fourth iteration - i need to read from txt2.csv and 2nd line.

Below is my setup

Step 1 : Currently i created one csv files c://user/master.csv in these i put two files names txt1.csv, txt2.csv

Step 2 : I created a csv data setup config and configured c://user/master.csv as filepath and kept filename as variable

Step 3 : I am reading the values from file like below

Username : ${__CSVRead(${filename},0}
Password : ${__CSVRead(${filename},1}.

While running its fetching the first row only from both files. It's not iterating each lines for per iteration. I want to iterate each lines in both files for per iteration. Even i used ${__CSVRead(${filename},next} in password column, but its not fetching any value.

May i know how to achieve this scenario.